# Clipboard Managers: How to assign keyboard shortcuts for pasting the 2nd or 3rd previously copied clipboard entries?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, clipboard

I use Ditto in Windows, and often use the custom keyboard shortcuts for pasting the 2nd or 3rd previously copied clipboard entries. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu? I have tried all the clipboard managers and don't see a way to do it in any of them. Whichever clipboard manager which allows this will be the one I choose. Many thanks.

Comment: "I have tried all the clipboard managers" would be nice if you listed them so we do not need to check them ourself ;-) clipman (xfce)? copyq? diodon (ubuntu), gpaste (gnome3)?

Comment: No need to check them anew yourself. Just looking if someone already knows of a program that offers it.